# How do I show that the conditional expectation equals the conditional probability?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation

We are told that $X$ is a uniformly integrable random variable on $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$. Let $A \in \mathcal{A}$, with $\mathbb{P}(A) \ne 0$.

Then,

$$ \mathbb{E}[X|A] \equiv \frac{1}{\mathbb{P}(A)} \int_{A} X(\omega)\ d\mathbb{P}(\omega) \equiv \frac{1}{\mathbb{P}(A)} \int_{\Omega} X(\omega)\ \mathbb{I}_{A}(\omega)\ d\mathbb{P}(\omega) \equiv \frac{\mathbb{E}[X \mathbb{I}_{A}]}{\mathbb{P}(A)}$$

Where $\mathbb{I}$ is the indicator function. We are asked to show as an exercise that $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{I}_{A_{1}}|A_{2}] = \mathbb{P}(A_{1} | A_{2})$.

I can see how $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{I}_{A_{1}}|A_{2}] = \mathbb{E}(A_{1} | A_{2})$ is true, and can show that, but not how the conditional expectation is equal to the conditional probability. We are told nothing on $A_{1}$ or $A_{2}$. I assume by default they must both be $\mathcal{A}$-measurable.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

$$
\mathbb{E}[I_{A_1} |A_2] = P[A_1 |A_2]\times 1 + P[\bar  A_1 |A_2]\times 0 = P[A_1 | A_2] 
$$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $A_1, A_2 \in \mathcal{A}$ and $\mathbb{P}(A_2) > 0$ so that both sides are well-defined, you have

$$ \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{I}_{A_1}\mid A_2]
= \frac{\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{I}_{A_1}\mathbb{I}_{A_2}]}{\mathbb{P}[A_2]}
= \frac{\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{I}_{A_1 \cap A_2}]}{\mathbb{P}[A_2]}
= \frac{\mathbb{P}[A_1 \cap A_2]}{\mathbb{P}[A_2]}
= \mathbb{P}[A_1 \mid A_2]. $$

To be honest, I have no idea what the notation $\mathbb{E}[A_1 \mid A_2]$ means.

Comment: Conditional expectation surely?

Comment: @stuartstevenson, I mean, what does it means to take expectation to *events* rather than random variables?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I just realized, that it is even easier with your definition. By definition
$$\mathbb{E}[I_{A_1}|A_2] = \frac{1}{\mathbb{P}(A_2)}\int_{A_2} I_{A_1} d\mathbb{P} = \frac{1}{\mathbb{P}(A_2)}\int_{A_1 \cap A_2} d\mathbb{P} = \frac{\mathbb{P}(A_1 \cap A_2)}{\mathbb{P}(A_2)} = \mathbb{P}(A_1|A_2)$$

**Alternatively**

Assuming your probability space is $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$. We have by definition (Edit: Well.. depending on how you defined it, i guess. But the following holds true.) 
$$\mathbb{E}[I_{A_1}|A_2] = \int_\Omega I_{A_1}(\omega) d\mathbb{P}(\omega|A_2)$$
Here I used the notation $I_{A_1}(\omega) = I_{\{\omega\in A_1\}}$. Now consider 
\begin{align*}
  \int_\Omega I_{A_1}(\omega) d\mathbb{P}(\omega|A_2) &= \int_{A_1} 1 d\mathbb{P}(\omega|A_2)\\
  &= \mathbb{P}(A_1|A_2)
\end{align*}
Done.

Comment: Btw I don't think $\mathbb{E}[I_{A_1}| A_2] = \mathbb{E}[A_1| A_2] $ holds true in general, as you mentioned in your question.